# Different reminders for each attendee

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'd like to know if is possible to send different notification for each attendee of the event.
here is my code:

```
    'attendees' => array(
                array('email' => $event["email"], 'displayName' => $event["displayname"]),
array('email' => $event["email2"], 'displayName' => $event["displayname2"]),
            ),
            'reminders' => array(
                'useDefault' => FALSE,
                'overrides' => array(
                    'overrides' => array(
                        //array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 60),
                        array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 1440),
                        array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no mention of customized calendar notifications mentioned [Reminders and Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders#notifications). As far as the docs go:

**Notifications**

Calendar support the following notification types:

- *Event creation*: a new event has been added to one of the user's calendars.
- *Event change*: an event the user is invited to has been modified by the organizer.
- *Event cancellation*: an event the user was invited to has been cancelled.
- *Attendee response*: an attendee to an event created by the user has changed their response status.
- *Agenda*: a list of all the events in the user’s calendar, sent at the start of the day.
  The user can decide what notifications to enable per calendar and the delivery method for each notification type. These settings are not shared with other users. Similar to default reminders, they’re accessible through the CalendarList collection.

**Delivery mechanisms**

The delivery methods offered by Google Calendar are:

- *Pop-up*. These are supported on mobile platforms and on web clients.
- *Email* sent by the server.
- *SMS*. These are only available for Google
  Apps for Work, Education, and Government customers.